# DynamoDB returning empty result set

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, empty-list

DynamoDB returning empty result set while scanning. Table having 15000 thousand rows but it is scanning 12000 rows only and returning empty result set.

Comment: Please provide some details. An [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. As it stands, there is no possible way to answer this question.

Comment: $response = $dynamodb->scan ([
  'TableName' => 'ExampleTable',
   'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
           ':val1' => ['N' => $site_id]
        ],
        'FilterExpression' => 'SiteId = :val1',
        //'Limit' => 1
  ]
   );   This peice of data i am using in my code. In development environment this code is working fine with few records. But in live it is not working. Any idea?